# How do I load money into my bitcoin account

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I don't understand how I load money into my bitcoin account so I can send it to someone

Comment: The process of trading money for some amount of a commodity is known as "buying". So what you are asking is how do you buy bitcoins. The short answer is that you find someone willing to sell them to you and give them money.

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin is an asset that you can purchase, more like an electronic version of a precious metal coin than like a payment service that you load money into.

To get Bitcoin you need to buy it from someone else or have someone pay you with it for providing some product or service.

To buy Bitcoins you can use services like Bitcoin exchanges (Popular exchanges in the US today are services like Gemini and Coinbase) or you can meet people in person and trade for bitcoin peer to peer (a popular service is localbitcoins).  The set of services available to you will be different depending on where you are.

As always, beware of scams online.  If you have any friends that use Bitcoin you can ask them for advice about what services they use.